# Eclipse RCP + Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, eclipse-rcp

I have a desktop application (built using Eclipse RCP) which on start, pops open a dialog box with 'UserName' and 'Password' fields in it. I need different types of authentication (LDAP, JDBC. etc).

If it was a web application the best way would be using Spring Security for this purpose. But I have Eclipse RCP application. Is there any way to integrate Eclipse RCP and Spring Security?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse RCP has security features available which you can use. The security is also JAAS compatible, so if you would like to hook Spring Security to it..it should be something doable.

Try the following links and see if you they serve your need without Spring Security:

- [Equinox Security Integration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/Equinox_Security_Integration)
- [Adding Security to Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/security/documents/addingsecurity/Adding%20Security%20to%20Eclipse.pdf)